# How many permutations of 1, 2,..., n yield a skew tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, permutation

How many permutations of 1, 2,..., n yield a skew tree (i.e., a tree of height n − 1)?

Since I know that any one skew tree is generated by just one permutation, this is asking for the number of skew trees of n nodes. How exactly would I go about finding it knowing the permutation formula?

Comment: Each node (except for the last) has either a left child or right child, so there's 2^(n-1) skew trees.

Comment: There is no commonly accepted definition of skew tree. Some define it as (1) a tree where all nodes have no more than one child. Others define it as (2) a tree where either all children are left or all children are right. Still others (the majority it seems) say (1) but mean (2). What is your definition? (In either case the formula is very simple).